# In Pandas, how can I find an index having calculated data which relates to it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of, let's say, fruits. Each fruit has a number of its varieties, and I want to find which fruit has the greatest number of them. By running this line I get that number:

```
max_var = fruits_df.groupby('Fruit')['Variety'].count().max()
```

VERY IMPORTANT EDIT: I re-formulated the explanation above since I mistook the index, it was not `'Fruit'`. Here I show some example data:

```
Index     Fruit     Variety
0         Berry     Blue  
1         Tomato    Saladet
2         Tomato    Cocktail
3         Mango     Ataulfo
4         Mango     Manila
5         Mango     Irwin
```

By running `max_var` it would equal 3. What do I have to do to get "Mango" from `Fruit` column as result, having that max_var = 3?

Comment: Maybe you want to add some data so that the example is complete.

Comment: But, what if you had another fruit, lets say apple, with three varieties in your example. Which would you expect now as fruit if `max_var` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

First you can add a count column to the dataframe by initializing it to 1

```
df['count'] = 1
```

Next, you groupby fruit and calculate the sum of each fruit

```
max_fruit = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Fruit')['count'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False))
```

Finally, max_fruit will give you the below output

```
       count
Fruit   
Mango   3
Tomato  2
Berry   1
```

Comment: This is something similar to what I have so for. But, how can I get the name of the fruit if `Fruit` is not the index? A pseudocode for it would be "Print the value in `Fruit` where max_fruit is maximum"

Comment: I wanted to do somewhat similar to what you are asking. I assigned  index to my column and got the value and then I used reset_index so that dataframe remains same. If you are able to get a better solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) rather than `max` to get the row name corresponding to the (first) maximum value

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. Based on the response of @Pritesh Choksi, I made a new dataframe with the fruits and the number of them (a short form of the first df). Then, as @Tom suggested, using `.idxmax()` the return sentence retrieves `"Mango"`. Thanks for your help!

```
short_df = df[['Fruit','variety']].copy().groupby('Fruit')['Variety'].count()
```

Gives:

```
Fruit     count()
Berry     1
Tomato    2
Mango     3
```

Finally:

```
return short_df.idxmax() =====> "Mango"
```